# ASP.NET browser back firing button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, back-button, page-lifecycle

I have a problem where an event is firing unexpectedly when the user hits the back button on the browser. Here are the steps.

1. User clicks button (fires btnNewSurvey_Click)
2. Browser displays popup window
3. User closes popup and navigates to a second page from a separate link.
4. Browser displays second page
5. User clicks back
6. btnNewSurvey_Click is fired again (this is the problem)

I was wondering why this is occurring. I've looked into asp.net's page life cycle as well as turning off caching for the page but I cannot reach an explanation.

Let me know if anymore information is required. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: It seems like the button click event is only getting fired when the user clicks back from chrome

aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewSurvey" runat="server" Text="New Survey" OnClick="btnNewSurvey_Click" />
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void btnNewSurvey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rwScreenList.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
    rwScreenList.Visible = true;
    ListBox lbox = rwScreenList.ContentContainer.FindControl("lboxScreenSelection") as ListBox;
    ((Label)rwScreenList.ContentContainer.FindControl("lblScreenError")).Text = "";
    lbox.DataSource = DatabaseFactory.GetScreensForProject(ProjectId);
    lbox.DataBind();
}
```

The problem is that this event is being called when the user hits back from another page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in your `rwScreenList.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;`

As i saw this is telerik property and when you use this property you need to go through certain things.

You can do like this also:

```
rwScreenList.VisibleOnPageLoad = !Page.IsPostBack;
```

Please refer below discussion which will help you to resolve from the problem.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/radwindow-reopening-after-closing-it-in-every-postback.aspx

Comment: The problem lies with the fact that the Button Click event is getting fired in the first place. Even if I comment out everything in that event block, it is still getting fired.

Comment: have u kept debugger on page load? does it goes on page load?

Comment: When the user hits back from the second page the debugger hits page load first. I would've thought that it would end there but after that it then hits btnNewSurvey_Click.